# Cassandra UDT TYPE remove a field name

Tags: cassandra, cql, cassandra-3.0

I have a UDT type in Cassandra. I want to ALTER this type to remove the country field.  I don't find any delete or remove field for ALTER TYPE documentation.  https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlAlterType.html

```
create type bank_payment (
      account_number text,
      name text,
      city text,
      country text,
      key text
);
```

Please help sharing ALTER command to remove one field from above UDT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cassandra UDT doesn't store any actual data and its the table where this UDT referred to has actual data. So go ahead and drop the UDT & recreate it with the correct definition that you want. Remember the serialization of old sstables that had this UDT (with additional column) will be different from the new one.

So if possible add a new version name to this UDT as you recreate, say

> bank_payment_v2

Comment: if the original table has a reference to the above type, cassandra won't allow dropping the type. For this alter table to remove the reference, drop and recreate the table, then alter again to add the type